# Is there an easy way to toggle display settings between 1 and 2 monitors?

Tags: windows-vista, multiple-monitors

I currently open Display settings, have to click 2nd monitor, check "extend desktop" & "use as primary", apply, then move 1 to the right 2 (fortunately the image only, not the monitor itself) - but that's too much clicking, there must be tools to make this a one-click operation...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[UltraMon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/overview/) has a nifty solution called [Display Profiles](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/tour/display_profiles.asp) which allows you to do this in 2 clicks from your system tray:

[image]

UltraMon is not free (shareware) but it has a ton of other features as well making it worthwhile :)

Comment: You're more than welcome!